# Firebase auth async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, async-await, firebase-authentication

I'm new to using async await and I'm trying a Auth `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` in firebase.

**signUp**

```
exports.signup = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, confirmPassword, handle } = req.body

    const newUser = {
        email,
        password,
        confirmPassword,
        handle
    }

    try {
        const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
        const token = response.getIdToken()
        console.log('THIS IS THE RESPONSE', token)
        // return token
        return res.status(200).json({
            message: 'User Successfully Added!',
            token: token
        })

    } catch (err) {
        if (err.code === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Email already taken!'
            })
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'Something went wrong, Please try again later'
            })
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is this is actually creating an account but always returning a status of **500** Something went wrong, Please try again later

#### EDIT:

`console.log(err)` gives the following output:

> TypeError: response.getIdToken is not a function

I'll try to look into it.

Comment: So what's exactly in `err`?

Comment: @zerkms I edited my question it looks like my getIdToken() is throwing an error

Comment: It's not `getIdToken` throws, but invoking `response.getIdToken()` which is not a function. Where is `response.getIdToken` defined?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns [Promise< UserCredential >](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth.html#returns-promise--usercredential-) And `getIdToken` is a method of user ([Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User.html))

```
const response = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password);
const token = await response.user.getIdToken(); // getIdToken is a method of user
console.log('THIS IS THE RESPONSE', token);
// return token
return res.status(200).json({
    message: 'User Successfully Added!',
    token: token
});
```

Comment: Put await also in response.user.getIdToken() because it will throw an error